# ASP.Net MVC Paging returns one large resultset instead of splitting resultset into pages

Tags: skip, pagedlist, take

I am using Paging in my View and originally my @model was of type PagedList.IPagedList but I was having issues posting back the IPagedList interface back to controller, therefore, I found a post that gave a hint on how to deconstruct my IPagedList so I could present it in the View and be able to post back to controller for further processing as well. However, I ran into the following issue - I want to display only 50 records on each page. The search criteria I am testing returns 13000 records. I am expecting only 50 records on first page with page numbers 1,2,3 at bottom. I see the page numbers as expected at the bottom but all 13000 records get displayed on every page. I have debugged the code and found out that `StaticPagedList` function is returning 13000 records instead of 50 so I applied Skip and Take on the object before returning it to the View but the issue is still occurring. My code:
View Models -

```
    public class PagedClientViewModel
{
    public int? Page { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectTimeTrackerEditorViewModel> Clients { get; set; }
    public IPagedList PagingMetaData { get; set; }
}

public class SelectTimeTrackerEditorViewModel
{
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
    public int SID { get; set; }
    public string PerNo { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

View -

```
@model EmergencyResponseTimeEntry.Models.PagedClientViewModel
```

@using PagedList;
@using PagedList.Mvc;

```
        @foreach (var item in Model.Clients)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.Selected)
                </td>

                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PerNo)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    
        
        Page @(Model.PagingMetaData.PageCount < Model.PagingMetaData.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PagingMetaData.PageNumber) of @Model.PagingMetaData.PageCount
        @Html.PagedListPager(new StaticPagedList<EmergencyResponseTimeEntry.Models.SelectTimeTrackerEditorViewModel>(Model.Clients, Model.PagingMetaData), page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }), new PagedListRenderOptions { DisplayEllipsesWhenNotShowingAllPageNumbers = false})
```

Controller -

```
var list = (from c in timeTrackers

                                    select new SelectTimeTrackerEditorViewModel
                                        { 
                                            Selected = false,
                                            SID = c.SID,
                                            PerNo = c.PerNo,
                                            FirstName = c.FirstName,
                                            LastName = c.LastName
                                        });

        var pagedClientViewModel = new PagedClientViewModel
        {
            Clients = list
        };
       
        int pageSize = 50;
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);

        int totalClients = list.Count();

        // List of current page of 50 records (hits database again, pulls only 50 records, though)
        var timeTrackerList = list.Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();

        

        pagedClientViewModel.PagingMetaData = new StaticPagedList<SelectTimeTrackerEditorViewModel>
            (timeTrackerList, pageNumber, pageSize, totalClients).GetMetaData();

        return View(pagedClientViewModel);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working after co-worker pointed out that I was displaying all records in my view - Model.Clients. So in my controller, I changed this

```
var pagedClientViewModel = new PagedClientViewModel
        {
            Clients = list
        };
```

to this -

```
var pagedClientViewModel = new PagedClientViewModel
        {
            Clients = list.Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList()
        };
```

Now paging is working as expected!